# Bootstrap modal bug when open ONLY on iphone/ipad

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, popup

I observe a very strange bug on iphone (and ipad) when I open a Bootstrap modal.
The black (semi opaque) background is well show, but the modal is not display. There is nothing visible and the user is blocked.

I'm using the following lib:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I already understood a possible reason, I include all the content of the modal inside an html table. In the follwing exemple, we can see two working case and the one concerned by the bug:

```
    <!-- debug popup -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" class="no-js">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="keywords" content="test" />
    <meta name="author" content="Kaio Gaming" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.blabl.fr/favicon.ico" sizes="96x96" type="image/x-icon" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="/membreDev/js/modernizr.js?version=1.0.3a"></script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fork-awesome@1.1.7/css/fork-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.js"
        integrity="sha256-2JRzNxMJiS0aHOJjG+liqsEOuBb6++9cY4dSOyiijX4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>debug popup</title>
    <meta name="description" content="debug popup de Kaio Gaming" />

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <center>
                <h1>debug popup</h1>
            </center>
            <div class="row float-right">
                <a type="button" href="../index.php" class="btn btn-danger">&larr;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <main role="main">
        <div class="container marketing">
            <h1>Working case #1: button and modal content directly in HTML root code</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger col-12" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                title="Faire une demande" id="btn-demande-acces" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popup-demande-acces"
                data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
                Demander un accès
            </button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="popup-demande-acces" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby=""
                aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <center>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modTitle">Faire une demande d'accès</h4>
                            </center> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                    aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" id="submitModalDemandeAcces">
                                <div class="form-group hide">
                                    <label for="Demandeur" class="control-label">Demandeur:
                                    </label>
                                    <select required="" value="1" class="custom-select" id="Demandeur"
                                        placeholder="Demandeur à définir" name="Demandeur">
                                        <option value="blablabla">blablabla (Exemple)</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Type" class="control-label">Type:
                                    </label>
                                    <select value="1" class="custom-select" id="Type" required=""
                                        placeholder="Type à définir" name="Type">
                                        <option value="1">Example</option>
                                    </select></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Details_de_la_demande" class="control-label">Détails de la demande:
                                    </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="Details_de_la_demande"
                                        id="Details_de_la_demande" required=""
                                        placeholder="Détails de la demande à définir">
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <center> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" title="Ajouter ➕">Ajouter
                                            ➕</button>
                                        <button id="demande_annulation" type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                            data-dismiss="modal">Annuler ⨯</button> </center>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <h1>Working case #2: the button is in the table, but the content is outside the table</h1>
            <div class="table-responsive ">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <center>Membre</center>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <center></center>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="rows countLineId row_1">
                            <td><span title="membre-97">ssj (ssj)</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#contactModal_97">Contacter</button>
                                </center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <!-- modal body outside the TABLE -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="contactModal_97" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Contacter membre"
                aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="viewMembre" title="Contact">
                                Contacter <a title="Voir le profil membre"
                                    href="https://www.blabla.fr/monCompte/maPage.php?pseudo=ssj">ssj:
                                    ssj</a>
                            </h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Email: <a href="mailto:ss@gmail.com">ss@gmail.com</a>
                                </li>

                                <li>Portable: <a href="tel:97678">97678</a></li>
                                <li>Discord: 0999897</li>
                                <li>Adresse postal: <a target="_blank"
                                        href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/blabla FRANCE"
                                        title="Google Maps">blabla, FRANCE</a> </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <h1>ERROR case: the open modal button AND the content is inside the table</h1>
            <div class="table-responsive ">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <center>Membre</center>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <center></center>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="rows countLineId row_1">
                            <td><span title="membre-96">ssj (ssj)</span></td>
                            <td>
                                <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#contactModal_96">Contacter</button>
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="contactModal_96" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                                        aria-labelledby="Contacter membre" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="viewMembre" title="Contact">
                                                        Contacter <a title="Voir le profil membre"
                                                            href="https://www.blabla.fr/monCompte/maPage.php?pseudo=ssj">ssj:
                                                            ssj</a>
                                                    </h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                                                        aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li>Email: <a href="mailto:ss@gmail.com">ss@gmail.com</a>
                                                        </li>

                                                        <li>Portable: <a href="tel:97678">97678</a></li>
                                                        <li>Discord: 976575</li>
                                                        <li>Adresse postal: <a target="_blank"
                                                                href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/blabla FRANCE"
                                                                title="Google Maps">blabla, FRANCE</a> </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                        data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hey Nico, don't paste php code here, show us your html page source (the rendered) on client browser so that community can try to replicate your issue, see more details here > https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and also share js and css that you use

Comment: I'm already think about a JS solution, moving all the modal content code outside the HTML table... but this is really bad, I would prefer to fix the bug in css ^^

Comment: Ok @KresimirPendic, sorry, I will update my question ;)

Comment: Done, I replace source code by the HTML generated on my page - except the CSS (because it is too big)

Comment: If you want help me and **check the result on iphone**, I create a page with the exemple here [link](https://www.kaiogaming.fr/ninjaDev/proto/debugPopup.php)
There is no authentication needed, please have a look ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I fixed my bug** using a "dirty" code.

I add in all my modal body elements a specific class (moveModalBody) and I move them in another place (a div in the head, in my case, but maybe in the footer or at the end of the body should be better...)

```
<script>
/* MOVE modal body: 
    All HTML code with the class modalBodyToMove  (modal created in sql2html)
    must mouve in div identifier moveModalHere (div in the generic header)
    to move them out of everything (specially the HTML tables)
*/
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.modalBodyToMove');
var classCount = elements.length;
console.log("Number of class modalBodyToMove: "+classCount);
if (classCount > 0){
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('moveModalHere').appendChild(  elements[i] )
    }
}
</script>
```

Of course, this script is added at the end of the page (after all the modal bodies are added)

**NOTE**: I added a check on the sum to avoid the js error in case of no modal on the page ^^

**Question**: I do believe this solution can impact the speed of my page (depending of the browser and the device...) I already open a bug issue on [github twitter/bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/31638) but if someone have a better idea, I'm open to test
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Only workaround that I'd use is to apply same `modal-dialog-centered` class on all modal popup html blocks - because it looks like iphone positioning is always going to position it on top of the page (and in your case it looks like it is no show - but it is actually up there :( ) see short demo here >

[image]

If you have time I think this could be valid for submitting under issues @github repo of bootstrap, but the process from submitting it > to actually be pushed down the wire at cdn's or elsewhere is somewhat longish, so that's why I'd use either `modal-dialog-centered` or use custom css for modals to position where you need it

Comment: This is a really good answer (I curious to know which tool did you use to generate this GIF). Before submit you post as the answer, may I ask you which kind of CSS should I add? A specific one for iOS (like media query) or a custom css to fix z-index and position ? Can you help me again?